# FATAL EXCEPTION,java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError - eclipse

Tags: java, android

Created a simple hello world app which works when I upload it through eclips to the AVD for the first time. But when I close it and try to open it again in the AVD it starts up and then the message "Unfortunately (appname) has stopped" pops up.

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example.robin;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

And my Android manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.robin"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
 </application>

</manifest>
```

And the LogCat:

```
09-28 10:24:41.903: W/dalvikvm(2794): VFY: unable to resolve static field 1864 (ActionBarWindow)      in Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable;
09-28 10:24:41.903: D/dalvikvm(2794): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0004
09-28 10:24:41.973: D/AndroidRuntime(2794): Shutting down VM
09-28 10:24:41.983: W/dalvikvm(2794): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception      (group=0x40a71930)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegate.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegate.java:106)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onCreate(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:57)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onCreate(ActionBarActivity.java:99)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at   com.example.hello.ROBIN_APP.onCreate(ROBIN_APP.java:13)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-28 10:24:42.003: E/AndroidRuntime(2794):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: If you don't need, remove the v7 library reference, use a standard activity and try again. Eclipse puts reference to the v7 library even if it's not needed at all.

Comment: I replaced "import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity" with "import android.app.Activity" but its the same problem and its complaining about the v7 support like before.

Comment: remove v7 library as dependecy: right-click on the project -> properties -> Android. Remove the library

Comment: Do you want the ActionBar to show or not?